# AndroidDriver cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, android, selenium, browser-automation

I am new to java. I am trying to create a sample mobile automation testing application using Selenium web driver for android. 
I have installed the Android SDK and started the Android emulator based on the guidelines from the below links. 
http://www.abodeqa.com/2013/05/08/configuring-android-webdriver-in-eclipse/ 
http://selenium.polteq.com/en/running-tests-on-an-android-simulator/ 
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver

I added the external jar files for selenium (`selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2`) and started the emulator using apk (`android-server-2.38.0.apk`) and added the code from the links.

I get reference errors for android driver as (`The import.org.selenium.android cannot be resolved`)

```
import org.openqa.selenium.android.AndroidDriver;
```

and in the below code as (*Android driver cannot be resolved to a type*)

```
AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver();
```

How to solve these reference errors for android ?. 
Any suggestions will be greatly helpful.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT : Added Screenshot
[image: Screenshot android reference error]

Comment: did u added jar in build path?

Comment: yes. added selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar file as external jar file

Comment: can u post screenshot or like so?

Comment: I think you should use selendroid.

Answer (score 4):

I think so android driver is belongs to java-client library so giving an error that android driver cannot resolve as type. please add java-client library and then import android driver that can solve problem.
this link can help you with java-client :-http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client
and then user import statement in eclipse :-
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
Try this it may help you

Answer (score 3):

I had faced same problem in Windows 7 64-bit.

Doing below steps my error got solved:-

- Downloaded Java-client jar from
  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client/2.1.0.
- Add the Jar to Build Path of my project. [Right click >>> Build Path >>> 
  Configure build path >>> Libraries tab >>> Add external jars >>> Now select your downloaded java-client].
- Now in your class add import as :import 
  io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
- Save the class.

After following above steps i am successfully able to access Android drivers.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are running a maven java project, add the following dependency to your POM and that should add the java-client jars to your project automatically. Once added, the error should go away.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>io.appium</groupId>
<artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
<version>5.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
```

in your Code:

```
driver= new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
```